# Calling transaction methods inside another transactional method using selfinjection

Tags: spring

So one transactional method calls another two transactional methods through selfinjection. If the very last transactional method throws an exception, the second method does not rollback its changes.
Any solution on how to fix it?

```
@Transactional
method a {
}

@Transactional
method b {
  throw SQLexeption
}

@Transactional
method c {
  serviceClass.a
  serviceClass.b
}
```

Comment: In a normal case it should do the rollback, so I doubt that this dumbed down version of the code actual shows your actual issue. Is there a try/catch in there? What is the transactional configuration (i.e. the `@Transactional`). In short there is too little information here.

Answer (score 2):

From your question i assume that you want to rollback every changes even if the last method has some exception.
if you want to rollback all your transaction you can annotate `@Transactional` to the main(Parent) method which calls other methods.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public void yourParentMethod(){
  yourOtherMethods();
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I,ve tried using the same but with RunTimeException and it didnt work. Mb I did a mistake somewhere else...
Anyway that helped me. Thanks!

Comment: The rollback should normally already happen, at least with the simple code shown in the answer. Adding a `rollbackFor` won't help with that.